# Active Directory profile problem <username>.V2 - windows 7

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I'm using Windows7 on my workstation
My domain account name is "alexb"

My profiles are located in //main/profiles/
So, in that shared dir, i have //main/profiles/alexb
this seems out of date... 
there is //main/profiles/alexb.V2 that is up to date, however i can't seem to make it "revert" back to using just alexb, even though my profile location is set correctly in my active directory user settings etc...

I've tried deleting BOTH the profile folders (alexb and alexb.V2) however, when i log back in, it just re-creates the V2 one, and puts my stuff in there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is just the way Vista/Windows 7/Windows 2008 works.  The new profile will have a .v2 extension.  See [Managing Roaming User Data Deployment Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/b/a/3ba6d659-6e39-4cd7-b3a2-9c96482f5353/Managing%20Roaming%20User%20Data%20Deployment%20Guide.doc).

The new profiles are not compatible with Windows 2000/2003/XP.  I think the incompatibility is a good reason for a different folder name.  It helps you to know what version of windows the profile is for.

Answer (score 0):

So the real answer is in subheading "Compatibility with previous user profiles" below "Compatibility with Application and User Profiles from Previous Versions of Windows" where it says that "[t]he 'v2' is to used isolate Windows Vista roaming user profiles from roaming user profiles created by previous operating systems."